# python list comprehension with for loops and statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I would like to know if is possible to make this with a list comprehension.
The line "total = 0" is what gives the error

```
listoflists=[[1,2,5],[1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1]]
result=[]

for lis in listoflists:
    total = 0
    for i in lis:
        if i==1:
            total+=1
    result.append(total)
```

All i can think of is

```
    result = [total for lis in listoflists total=0 for i in lis if i==1 total +=1]
```

But of course doesn't work, I can't find how to handle statements that aren't ifs or for loops (in this case the "total") in list comprehensions

any help would be appreciated

Comment: it's not possible in a list comprehension alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in this case

```
[l.count(1) for l in listoflists]
```

is an efficient answer.

Conceptually to handle some arbitrary aggregation (say different from a simple sum) in your case `total` on a sublist you can use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
from functools import reduce
[reduce(lambda total,x:total + (1 if x==1 else 0),l,0) for l in listoflists]
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of `1` occurrences in each sublist:

```
listoflists = [[1,2,5],[1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1]]
result = [i.count(1) for i in listoflists]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#bytes.count

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this to get the total count of `1`:

```
result = sum([l.count(1) for l in listoflists])
```

or in case you need individual counts in the subarrays , this should do:

```
result = [l.count(1) for l in listoflists]
```

So,

```
listoflists = [[1,2,5],[1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1]]
result = sum([l.count(1) for l in listoflists]) # result = 6(1+3+2)
```

and :

```
listoflists = [[1,2,5],[1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1]]
result = [l.count(1) for l in listoflists] # result = [1, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> listoflists=[[1,2,5],[1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1]]
> [sum([x for x in xs if x == 1]) for xs in listoflists]
> [1, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with just plain list comprehensions.

You can use `[sum(filter(lambda x: x == 1, l)) for l in listsoflists]` if you're ok with using a few functions as well.

EDIT:

`[l.count(1) for l in listsoflists]` is of course better.